# Some Isaiah 61:8 translations use phrase "burnt offering" as opposed to "wrong"/"wrongdoing". Therefore, what does Hebrew WLC version say?

Tags: hebrew, psalms, hebrew-bible

It's big difference if some bible translations say:

the burnt offering

as opposed to

wrong/wrongdoing

Could some please read and evaluate the corresponding Hebrew WLC version, and give and elaborate explanation on what the Hebrew says?  Also, could someone please give more insight as to why the differences are there?

> Isaiah 61:8 (NASB) For I, the LORD, love justice, I hate robbery **in
> the burnt offering**; And I will faithfully give them their recompense
> And make an everlasting covenant with them.
>
> Isaiah 61:8 (KJV) For I the LORD love judgment, I hate robbery **for
> burnt offering;** and I will direct their work in truth, and I will
> make an everlasting covenant with them.
>
> Isaiah 61:8 (NLT) “For I, the LORD, love justice. I hate robbery **and
> wrongdoing.** I will faithfully reward my people for their suffering
> and make an everlasting covenant with them.
>
> Isaiah 61:8 (ESV) For I the LORD love justice; I hate robbery **and
> wrong;** I will faithfully give them their recompense, and I will make
> an everlasting covenant with them.

> Yesha'yah 61:8 (WLC)  8כִּ֣י אֲנִ֤י יְהוָה֙ אֹהֵ֣ב מִשְׁפָּ֔ט שֹׂנֵ֥א
> גָזֵ֖ל בְּעֹולָ֑ה וְנָתַתִּ֤י פְעֻלָּתָם֙ בֶּאֱמֶ֔ת וּבְרִ֥ית עֹולָ֖ם
> אֶכְרֹ֥ות לָהֶֽם׃

Comment: Robert Young makes the connection clearer : _For I `am' Jehovah, loving judgment, Hating **plunder for** a burnt-offering_. [YLT} What is hated is the offering up of that which was stolen. And I think the KJV agrees with this. (Up-voted +1).

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtlety in the text as pointed out by several commentaries, see below.  Apparently, the LXX recognized this and either used an older version of the Hebrew text or corrected the copyists' mistake.  One form could easily be mistaken for the other text variant.

**Cambridge:**

> I hate robbery &c.] Render with R.V. I hate robbery with iniquity, and
> I will give them their recompense in truth (i.e. faithfully). Instead
> of שׂלָה (= burnt-offering) we must point עו̇לָה (= iniquity). The
> translation of the A.V. would shut us up to a wrong interpretation of
> the prophet’s thought. The robbery to which he refers is not that
> practised by Israelites on God (Malachi 3:8-9), but the iniquitous
> treatment of Israel by its foes.

**Ellicott**

> I hate robbery for burnt offering.—The Authorised Version follows the
> Vulg, and Luther, but the words, commonly applied as condemning the
> formal sacrifices of the wicked, do not fit in with the context, and
> it is better to take the rendering of the LXX. and the Targum, I hate
> robbery with violence, as referring to the spoliation which Israel had
> suffered at the hands of the Chaldæans.

**Pulpit**

> I hate robbery for burnt offering; rather, I hate robbery with
> wickedness (comp. Job 5:16; Psalm 58:3; Psalm 64:7; 92:16). The
> transplantation of nations was a gross abuse of the rights of
> conquest. I will direct their work in truth;

**Barnes**

> I hate robbery for burnt-offering - There has been great variety in
> the interpretation of this phrase. Lowth renders it, 'Who hate rapine
> and iniquity.' Noyes, 'I hate rapine and iniquity.' Jerome, as in our
> translation, Et odio habens rapinam in holocausto. The Septuagint,
> Μισῶν ἁρπάγματα ἐξ ἀδικίας Misōn harpagmata ech adikias -
> 'Hating the spoils of injustice.' The Chaldee, 'Far from before me be
> deceit and violence.' The Syriac, 'I hate rapine and iniquity.' This
> variety of interpretation has arisen from the different views taken of
> the Hebrew בעולה be‛ôlâh. The Syriac evidently prefixed the
> conjunction, ו (v), "and," instead of the preposition, ב (b), "with"
> or "for"; and, perhaps, also the Septuagint so read it. But this
> change, though slight, is not necessary in order to give a consistent
> rendering to the passage. The connection does not necessarily lead us
> to suppose that any reference would be made to 'burnt-offering,' and
> to the improper manner in which such offerings were made; but the idea
> is rather, that God hated rapine and sin; he hateth such acts as those
> by which his people had been removed from their land, and subjected to
> the evils of a long and painful captivity. And this is undoubtedly the
> sense of the passage. The Hebrew word עולה ‛ôlâh, usually without
> the ,ו means properly "a holocaust," or "what is made to ascend" (from
> עלה ‛âlâh, to ascend) from an altar. But the word here is the
> construct form for עולה ‛avı̂lâh, "evil, wickedness"; whence our word
> "evil" (see Job 24:20; Psalm 107:42). And the sense here is, hate
> rapine or plunder (גזל gāzēl) with iniquity;' that is, accompanied,
> as it always is, with iniquity and sin. And hating that as I do, I
> will vindicate my people who have been plundered in this way; and who
> have been borne into captivity, accompanied with deeds of violence and
> sin.